# "would" indicating probability?

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Does the "would" in the following examples have the same meaning? Some say "would" has the "probably" meaning, but I am not sure if it applies here. Do these sentences imply an unsaid if-clause?

> a. A: Who's ringing the doorbell? B: It'd (= would) be John.

> b. I think my swimming pool would hold 20,000 gallons of water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These both contain an implied "if". Both involve a person making a deduction or calculation and "if" is "if my calculations are correct"

> That would be John (I remember him saying that he would come round after lunch and I estimate that it is about 2pm now, so if my memory is correct and if nobody else is coming at the same time I deduce that it is John)

> ...would hold 20,000 gallons of water, if my mental calculation is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Is this "would" different from the "would" in "If I were a billionaire, I would buy a jet"?

Comment: 'Different' in that they are guesses at the correct answer rather than statements about a hypothetical situation.